# JavaFX8 secure session and connection to database

Tags: database, javafx-8

I'm building a JavaFX8 application.

In login page, how do I secure the transfer of account and password and do I have to use web service to do the identification?

```
Java Web Start <-----> Database
or
Java Web Start <-----> Web Service <----> Database
```

After login, page will redirected to "member data maintain", how do I keep the session to guarantee that user is qualified to access this page and do updates?

What's the normal way to deal the database connection in in JavaFX program?

thank you for your advice.

P.S. 1. I did google keywords for several days, appreciate anyone can help, thanks!

P.S. 2. found a similar question: [How are secure database connections usually implemented in JAR files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660154/how-are-secure-database-connections-usually-implemented-in-jar-files).

P.S. 3. My purpose is to connect DigitalPersona fingerprint reader on client (with Java Web Start)

Comment: Your question seems to have more relation to plain Java then databases or javafx-8. I recommend using the right tags, and include some source code to show what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: looks like [WebSocket](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/BinaryWebSocket/binaryWebSocket.html) is the solution, still try to learn that stuff.